# PHP: how can autoload work with multiple class in same file?

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

I'm working on an existing site done with Laravel 7 and PHP 7.2.24.

There is a controller which uses some constants:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Helpers\UserRole;


class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function me()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user->role == UserRole::ADMIN_COMPANY) {
         // do something
        }

        return response()->json($user, 200);
     }

}
```

`UserRole` is a class defined it a file declaring multiple classes, `Constant.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Constant
{
    const MAX_IMAGE_UPLOAD_SIZE_KB = 1024 * 10; 
    const MAX_DOC_UPLOAD_SIZE_LANDING = 1024 * 5; 
    const MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE_ORDER = 1024 * 10;
}

class UserRole
{
    const ADMIN = 1;
    const ADMIN_COMPANY = 2;
    const USER_COMPANY = 3;
}

//and other classes
```

If I try to run the code locally, I get the error `Class 'App\\Helpers\\UserRole' not found` which looks coherent to me, because as far as I know it doesn't respect the PSR-4 autoloader specification.

However, this does somehow works on the online server.
How and why is it working? How can I replicate the same on local environment?

Comment: Do `composer dump-autoload` an try again.

Comment: I tried it, but still same error. I also tried `php artisan optimize` `php artisan route:cache` without success